# Next Auth - MongoDB Adapter causes my homepage to 404

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to integrate Next Auth with my project using Next 13, following different tutorials I am trying to add a MongoDB adapter in my route file. It seems that when I add the MongoDB adapter my homepage gives me a 404 error and there are no errors in the console that give me any indicators. If I comment out that line and rebuild everything works as expected, it also works if I add the line back in after I've it's already running.

Does anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong?

This is the contents of my root file: `app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts`

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import clientPromise from '@/lib/mongodb';
import { MongoDBAdapter } from '@auth/mongodb-adapter';
import type { Adapter } from 'next-auth/adapters';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';

const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: String(process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID),
      clientSecret: String(process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET),
    }),
  ],
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise) as Adapter, // The line which is erroring
  jwt: {
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Comment: i think the issue lies with your routing... there is no need for a `route.ts` file Your next-auth code should go in `[...nextauth].ts` `app/api/auth` are all folders and `[...nextauth]` should be a file not a folder. https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/example

Comment: @Nikster: Note that Next.js 13.2 changed the recommended pattern _again_, using [Route Handlers](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/initialization#route-handlers-app), that is indeed `/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts` instead of `pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js`.